# CSFML - Toggle input issue

Tags: c, toggle, sfml, 2d-games

So I'm trying to make an entire game on my own, and I got into the part where I make an inventory. I want to make a toggle input on the key E to open the inventory, but when I try in-game the feature, sometimes when I press E, my inventory open and close at the same time, sometimes when it's open, it won't close when I press E, but when I press E again, it close.

Here's the code :

```
int isOpen = inventory->isOpen;

if (inventory->isOpen == NO && sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyE)) {
    openInventory(inventory);
    inventory->isOpen = YES;
    return;
}
if (isOpen == YES && sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyE)) {
    closeInventory(inventory);
    inventory->isOpen = NO;
    return;
}
```

I try to sync the inventory's opening on the sfClock with a tick of 0.10f just like the tick I used to animate the sprite of the player, but still not working.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your inventory screen probably opens and closes repeatedly when the key is pressed. That is because of the following.

on the first iteration of the loop the key is pressed and the inventory screen is not opened so it gets opened.

On the second iteration of the loop the key is *still* pressed and the inventory screen is  opened so it gets closed.

The iterations sound like they are only 0.01s apart, and because sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed is only the *current* state of the keyboard, you need to manually detect when a key is newly pressed. (For something like this anyway, character movement is usually fine to be based on the current state.)

You should store the previous state of the key press and only perform your inventory open/close logic when it has changed from not pressed to pressed. For example:

```
bool previousKeyState = false;

// main loop
{
    keyState = sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyE);

    if ((!previousKeyState) && (keyState))
    {
        if (inventory->isOpen == NO) {
        // etc
        }
    }

    previousKeyState = keyState;
}
```

---

Here is an approximation of what I think is what is happening with your code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.h>

int main(void)
{
    bool    inventory_IsOpen = false;

    while (!sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyEscape))
    {
        if ((inventory_IsOpen == false) && sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyE)) {
            std::cout << "Open inventory" << std::endl;
            inventory_IsOpen = true;
        }
        else if ((inventory_IsOpen == true) && sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyE)) {
            std::cout << "Close inventory" << std::endl;
            inventory_IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And when I press the E key I get a stream of output like this:

```
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
Open inventory
Close inventory
```

[image: Existing output]

If I then change the example to the following:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.h>

int main(void)
{
    sfBool  previousKeyState = sfFalse;
    bool    inventory_IsOpen = false;

    while (!sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyEscape))
    {
        sfBool keyState = sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyE);

        if ((previousKeyState == sfFalse) && (keyState == sfTrue)) {
            if (inventory_IsOpen == false) {
                std::cout << "Open inventory" << std::endl;
                inventory_IsOpen = true;
            }
            else if (inventory_IsOpen == true) {
                std::cout << "Close inventory" << std::endl;
                inventory_IsOpen = false;
            }
        }

        previousKeyState = keyState;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I only get a single output when I press the key:

```
Open inventory
```

[image: Looking for new keypress]

Comment: But is there not a issue where the keyState value will change instantly with the second iteration ? So this will be the same problem. I tried your code and there's still the same problem unfortunately

Comment: @Servaloop it can change on any iteration, but because the code stores the value from the previous iteration the `if` only evaluates to true for a new press of the key. You would have to release and press the key on successive iterations to detect a new keypress. I would have thought any key debounce would be taken care of by the hardware/driver/os but maybe not? If not you’d need to compare the current state with the state from iterations further in the past.

Comment: @Servaloop I have also just noticed that you create a temporary variable `isOpen` which you only use once later in your code. I wonder if you are not showing us a complete example and there is something else happening?